# Trouble in fetching schedule no. line level field from amortization journal entry user event beforesubmit

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have created amortization schedule journal entry. need to fetch schedule no. field at line level. I have created user event beforesubmit script. I am able to fetch department, description, schedule no. field values in edit mode. department and description in create mode. but getting blank value in schedule no. field log even there is value at create mode. how to access this value?

/**

- @NApiVersion 2.x
- @NScriptType UserEventScript
  */

define(['N/record', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/ui/message', 'N/runtime'],

```
function (record, serverWidget, search, message, runtime) {

    function beforeSubmit(context) {
        // try {
                               
                var rec = context.newRecord;
                 
                
                var recType = rec.type;
                log.debug("recType",recType);
                

               //Journal Entry
                if (recType === 'journalentry') {
                    log.debug("context",context.type);
                      if (context.type === 'create') {
                    log.debug("creating......");
                    
                                                      
                    var numLines = rec.getLineCount({
                        sublistId: 'line'
                    });
                    log.debug("numLines", numLines);
                   
                    
                    for(var s=0;s<numLines;s++)
                    {
                          
                         var scheduleNo = rec.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'line',
                            fieldId: 'schedulenum',
                            line: s
                        });
                        log.debug("scheduleNo", scheduleNo);

                        var department = rec.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'line',
                            fieldId: 'department',
                            line: s
                        });
                        log.debug("department", department);

                        var decs = rec.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'line',
                            fieldId: 'memo',
                            line: s
                        });
                        log.debug("decs", decs);

               
                }

            
                }

               
            } 
    
    }

    return {
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
    }

});
```